# Changing the type of a nested JSON attribute

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
scala> val df = spark.read.json("data.json")

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- **TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)**
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)


scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("TimeStamp", $"TimeStamp".cast(TimestampType))

scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- **TimeStamp: timestamp (nullable = true)** // WORKING AS EXPECTED
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)


scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("a.b.c", $"a.b.c".cast(DoubleType))

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- **a.b.c: double (nullable = true)** // DUPLICATE COLUMN ADDED
```

I'm trying to change the type of a nested JSON attribute within a data frame column. the change in a nested attribute has been treated as a new column which resulting a duplicate column. the change is working fine for the top level attributes (Timestamp) but not for the nested ones (a.b.c). Any thoughts on this problem ?.

Answer (score 1):

since your column is of struct type & you need to build it again in the same hierarchy. Because it doesn't go by assumption, it thinks that you are rewriting the structure.
Input:

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": "1.31", "d": "1.11"}}, "TimeStamp": "2017-02-18", "id":1}
{"a": {"b": {"c": "2.31", "d": "2.22"}}, "TimeStamp": "2017-02-18", "id":1}

val lines2 = spark.read.json("/home/kiran/km/km_hadoop/data/data_nested_struct_col2.json")
lines2.printSchema()

val df2 = lines2.withColumn("a", struct(
                                    struct(
                                        lines2("a.b.c").cast(DoubleType).as("c"),
                                        lines2("a.b.d").as("d")
                                    ).as("b")))
            .withColumn("TimeStamp", lines2("TimeStamp").cast(DateType))
df2.printSchema()
```

This is output of both schemas before & after:

```
root
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)

root
 |-- TimeStamp: date (nullable = true)
 |-- a: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- c: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

I hope it is clear.

Comment: I tried to built using the same hierarchy for a -> b -> c. it works. but, this seems to work only if we have one attribute at the same level in the tree. if we have two attributes like a -> b -> c and a ->b -> d, then the a -> b -> d will be dropped and only a -> b -> c exists after the casting of a -> b -> c. so this may not work.

Comment: You are ignoring one thing, this solution is based on the limitation (at least as I know of) that there is no way to call an inner column by using dot notation inside Dataframe's withColumn() function. It accepts simple string of the column name to work on. So you would need to maintain the same structure, which is not scalable.. If the original structure is different, code also changes. I will add modified code as new answer because comments section doesn't allow formatting...